# Devise views not generating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Devise works. I can login and log out, but there are no views in the my project. There is no `app/views/devise` folder. When I used `rails g devise:views` nothing appeared. How is Devise even working if there is no html, and how can I get these views to display in my project so I can edit them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If files are not added, the files added into your `gem` folder and `Devise` will use them, but when you run the *command*, the created folder will just *overwrite* them.

If `rails g devise:views` still not working for you, one easy way to do this instead of trying to find what was the issue with the `gem` or Terminal is to just move them yourself.

Here you have the files [Devise views](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app/views/devise), just copy paste them into your folder and you will be good.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help

Answer (score 3):

Go to the application root directory and run following command to get views of devise:

```
rails g devise:views
```

Answer (score 1):

I read on the documentation that you have to put this line in config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.scoped_views = true
```

you will have access to the file for sessions,
and you can do too :

```
rails generate devise:views users
```

to have access to user files

You should take a look : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Hope that help

Comment: I ran that command and  it looks like the files were created, but there is still nothing in my project folder.

Comment: Did you try `rails generate devise:views User`?

Comment: @DavidK I think you should try to read this : https://blog.payload.tech/2016/03/18/custom-routes-and-views-with-devise/   all the answer are here

Comment: No. I had to manually put the devise files in, like was @user6589814 suggested.